# How to access the properties of nested objects in a for in loop in typescript?

Tags: typescript

You can check the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCKBXCNUF44DeAUHHFMAMYCGYAkgHYBmEAwhALbvD0wDOA-AC44vGFACW9AOZwAPnHoYANkpJwAJuN4UIGHkLgARLTr0wiRAL4XQkWAmSpj23Tzj5ipGNipLnp-WFFdgAjYCg5BWVVLx8lAEFGHCh-VxgDYLCI+UUVKwsdelE4CCV1TGxgYQqcd0I1cmo6JlYOLh5eYQAiAGsMKSp1XkYpLoAaNU0XM2FPUgQ41Jm4AGYAFgn5hZhfROSlnmEAJnXNuGtrIiVgeHpgAHcavEJLOCpedCwcC2YIgApCsUwFAIChYIg4JISmUngBKeqkQHwJAodQABRBYKQdWBoPC2PecB6wEQEEYn0qajujy+wAA2ijgOjMfjEABdOqlcq0hmOZl48FsiyWIA) for the code the issue is with the `newQuote.discount` nested object can't be assigned. Getting error  `Type 'null' is not assignable to type '(string & Discount) | undefined` .

```
type Quote = {
  recapInfoComments?: string | null
  discount?: Discount

}

type Discount = {
  totalDiscount?: number | null
  totalAfterDiscount?: number | null
}

const oldQuote: Quote = {
  recapInfoComments: "kugadsfg",
  discount: {
    totalDiscount: 34,
    totalAfterDiscount: 234,
  }
}

let newQuote = {} as Quote

for (const property in oldQuote) {
  const typedProperty = property as keyof Quote
  newQuote[typedProperty] = oldQuote[typedProperty]

}
```

Comment: How about using `Object.assign(newQuote,oldQuote);`?

Comment: Its part of a larger codebase where only parts of `oldQuote` are in `newQuote` hence the `for in` loop

Comment: Start with `let newQuote:{[key in keyof Quote]:any} = {}` and cast it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you know more than `ts` compiler, so you can use `as any` when assigning the value:

```
for (const property in oldQuote) {
  const typedProperty = property as keyof Quote
  newQuote[typedProperty] = oldQuote[typedProperty] as any;
}
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrge2NAvFA3gKClAThAYwEMwBJAOwDMEBhBAW3onOAGcB%20ALileFwEtyAcygAfKOTgAbKdigATfqwII4LLlAAiSlWuCZMAXwOhIWnapZQ0WHMCREp25ZeAbJ9AEYRcYidNk7BykAQUpkXGdddW4Pb19xSRkjAxVyXigEKXl4JAhuXORrDDl8YjIqWgYmFlZuACIAazghInlWSiF6gBo5RRc9blscKHtgRyjXbgBmABZekdHgsIjJwagAJjmFqGNjTCkIYAkIAHdC1AxDKCJWWERkAG4DTGpfAAo0jLBcBEhcUBQQSZbIXACUJRwX2Opgg8gACr9-oC0D8-j5AbcoI0ICAEJR7nk5OQzhcANqwhFIjEgAC6xSyOQeEAp4DhiPRALpNzuRHIIGe%20y%20WQgADopAghO8SedmWDHkA)

Answer (score 1):

In the specific example you've provided, you can use ES6 spread syntax to create a shallow clone of an object. This does the same thing your example wants to do:

```
let newQuote: Quote = {...oldQuote}
```

You can also do partial updates this way, e.g

```
let partOfQuote: Partial<Quote> = { 
    discount: {
        totalDiscount: null,
        totalAfterDiscount: null 
    } 
}
let newQuote: Quote = { ...oldQuote, ...partOfQuote }
```

---

Onto explaining what went wrong:

The type of the expression `oldQuote[typedProperty]` is `Quote[keyof Quote]` as you might expect. Its expanded type is `string | Discount | null | undefined`. That makes sense, we could get any one of those 4 things by using some unknown key to index into a `Quote`.

However, what will TypeScript let us assign to `newQuote[typedProperty]`? For type safety reasons, it picks the most restrictive option possible: the intersection of all of the types of the object's values.

As a concrete example, lets say we had this:

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

const somePersonKey: keyof Person = "firstName";
const billy: Person = { firstName: "billy", lastName: "johnson" };
```

Typescript would let us say `billy[somePersonKey] = "a string value"` because it knows that this is safe for all of the fields of `Person`. Now, say we updated our code as such to add a field with type `number`:

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number; // new field
} 

const somePersonKey: keyof Person = "firstName";
const billy: Person = { firstName: "billy", lastName: "johnson", age: 67 }
```

Now, `billy[somePersonKey] = "a string value"` no longer compiles. TypeScript sees that there is an `age` field with type `number`, so if `somePersonKey` was `"age"`, then the right hand side of the assignment would need to be a number. The only type that is safe for all keys of `Person` would be a type that is assignable to both `string` and `number`. This type is `string & number`, i.e `never`, meaning no such values exist.

However, one way to get around this is by using more specific types. If we had another constant

```
const personNameKey: "firstName" | "lastName" = "firstName";
```

then we would be allowed to do `billy[personNameKey] = "a name"`, because the type of the `firstName` field is `string`, and the type of the `lastName` field is `string`, meaning that we can assign strings to `billy[personNameKey]`. The type of `personNameKey` tells TypeScript that its value cannot be `age` i.e we won't run into a problem trying to assign a `string` to a `number` field.

---

In terms of applying this information to fix your loop example, I'm not sure if there is a way. You could have some array like

```
const quoteKeys = ["recapInfoComments", "discount"] as const
```

which lets you do `newQuote[quoteKeys[0]] = oldQuote[quoteKeys[0]]`. Unfortunately, looping over the values of quote keys (e.g `for (const key of quoteKeys) { ... }` or `quoteKeys.forEach((key) => { ... })` does not preserve the specific type, `key`'s type goes back to `keyof Person`, which is what we were trying to avoid.

Maybe you could get your example to typecheck using a recursive generic function. However, it would be easier to just use an `as any` typecast and add a comment explaining why doing so is type-safe.